# How to get thumbnail image using SDWebImage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdwebimage

I do not want to download the image from the server until the user selects it. I want to show the thumbnails for the image. How to get thumbnails? 
I am able to download the full image using the URL from the server.

If the image at server is of say 1MB, how to get its thumbnail version?

Comment: Do you have image absolute URL ? are you using objective c or swift ?

Comment: Yes I have the URL and I am able to download the full image from the server. I am using ObjectiveC.

Comment: at server side create 2 copies of image. initially load thumbnails then when user click on image load original image. even WhatsApp doing same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve your goal :

**Way 1:**

You can not get thumbnail. If you have file of size say 1 MB then you have to downloaded it using `SDWebImage`. When download completes create thumbnail of image. Now you can remove image of 1MB.

**Code for create thumbnail :**

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToFillSize:(CGSize)size
{

CGFloat scale = MAX(size.width/image.size.width, size.height/image.size.height);
CGFloat width = image.size.width * scale;
CGFloat height = image.size.height * scale;
CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake((size.width - width)/2.0f,
                              (size.height - height)/2.0f,
                              width,
                              height);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0);
[image drawInRect:imageRect];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return newImage;
}
```

**Way 2:**

At server side you have to keep both image original image and thumbnails. And so first load thumbnail using `SDWebImage`. When user click on thumbnail get original image from server using `SDWebImage`.

Comment: So you are saying that at server I need to keep 2 copies of the image. One for thumbnail and other for original? So Initially I need to fetch the thumbnail and if user selects the thumbnail then I have to download the complete image. 
I do not want to download the full image.  Are you sure about this? Is there any way to get out of this? I know instagram and google does similar to this.

Comment: @PayalManiyar : it is not good solution to download image first and then create thumbnail...!!

Comment: way 2 is better. I was saying about  way 1...!!

Answer (score 1):

You can't make changes to server from your `ios device`. you can just put data to server or fetch data from it. so, if big image is stored at server then you can't make it thumbnail from ios. you can just download it, once image comes to your device then you can modify it according to your need.

So, it is better way to keep two copies of same image to server and it is not hard task from server side. :)

Answer (score 0):

When you have absolute URL and just want to display image using SDWebImage.

Use below code

```
SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
    [manager downloadImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strDisplayURL]
                          options:0
                         progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {
                             // progression tracking code
                         }
                        completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished, NSURL *imageURL) {

                            if (image)
                            {

                              dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                                    profileImageView.image = image;

                                });

                            }

                        }];
```

Use image modes.

[image]

And make corner radius half of image view height or width. so it will become circle image view.